# Await result in js file with sqlite3

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, discord.js, node-sqlite3

I'm a discord bot developer and I use a database.db file as a database. I code in JS so i installed the sqlite3 module. My code for the 'messageCreate' event is right there:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "messageCreate",
  once: false,
  async execute(client, message) {
    let prefix;
    await client.db.get(
      `SELECT prefix FROM "Guilds" WHERE id = "${message.guild.id}"`,
      async (err, row) => {
        prefix = row.prefix;
      }
    );
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const cmdName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (cmdName.length == 0) return;

    let cmd = client.commands.get(cmdName);
    if (cmd) {
      cmd.run(client, message, args);
    }
  },
};
```

I want to put the resut of the `.get()` function in the `prefix` variable, but when I try to run the code, it returns undefined, so I did a `console.log()` and saw that the code didn't await the result and continued to run.
So the problem is that I don't know how to await the result of the `.get()` function. I tried to put an `await`, but i didn't do anything. Is there another way to wait the result and then create a variable with the result in it?

Comment: `client.db.get("...", (err, row) => {...})`  does not return a promise, thus it cannot be `await`ed .. Either use a library that supports promises or handle callbacks correctly ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Promise` constructor ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)).

```js
const prefix = await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  client.db.get(SQL,
    (err, row) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(row.prefix)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if there's an error? I speculate that you have an error in your SQL syntax, since you are putting quotes around the table name here:

```
SELECT prefix FROM "Guilds" WHERE id = "${message.guild.id}"
                   ^^^^^^^^
```

Add this for troubleshooting purposes and let me know what it returns:

```
      async (err, row) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        prefix = row.prefix;
      }
```

Comment: There was not any error, but now it works thanks